# Does $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability implies $\frac{1}{X_n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{X}$ in distribution for positive r.v.?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Does $X_n \rightarrow X$ in probability implies $\frac{1}{X_n} \rightarrow \frac{1}{X}$ in distribution for positive r.v. ?

I can not construct a counterexample for this but I can't think of a proof neither. A would be grateful for any hints or a solution.

Comment: $X_n \to X$ in probability iff every subsequence of $(X_n)$ has  a further subsequence which converges a.s. to $X$. So $\frac 1 {X_n}$ converges to $\frac  1 X$ in probability. Of course, convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Couldn't we use the fact that if $X_n \longmapsto X$ in probability then for a continuos function $f$ we have that $f(X_n) \longmapsto f(X)$, here using that the random variables are positive with $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} ?$ Edit: Yes sorry, I saw the conclusion of your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kavi Rama Murthy!

Comment: If $X_n$ or $X$ have a positive probability of being $0$ then you may have a difficulty

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem#Statement